# Is it possible to create several sharding keys for collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am confused a bit about sharding key in mongo.
Is it possible to use several sharding keys when you creates shard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shard key indexes are defined at the collection level and each collection within a database can only have a single shard key index. Within a sharded cluster you have the choice of sharding some or all collections.

It is important to note that shard keys are **immutable** and once the shard key is created, it cannot be modified.

For more information see:

[Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)

[Considerations for Selecting Shard Keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/)

Comment: although only a single shard key is allowed, it's worth to mention they can be a composite